# Determine path of class file that failed to load

Tags: java, runtime-error, classloader, .class-file

We get an `UnsupportedClassVersionError` but have problems identifying the location of the offending file (>15 JARs in the classpath, several of which may contain the particular class). We suspect that the same class may be in the class path multiple times.

Java option `-verbose:class` prints exactly what we want, but only for *successfully* loaded classes. The class (file) that causes the error is not printed.

How can we determine the physical location of the class file (most likely in a JAR) that causes the class loader error?

I thought it might be possible to set a breakpoint in `ClassLoader` but all the relevant methods are `native`.

Comment: Perhaps [Bad version number in .class file - how to find which class it is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710118/2711488) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's classloaders that rely on the class path at all search it *in order*, and use (or try to) the first definition they find for any given class they are trying to load.  In particular, it does not matter which class Java first discovers to require your problem class.  These class loaders perform the same path search for every class they try to load.

Very likely the class name -- especially its package -- will give you an idea of which jars to check, but you don't really need that.  The simplest and most reliable solution is to do as Java does: check each jar, in the order it appears in the class path.

You can list the contents of a jar with `jar -tf myjar.jar`.  If you are looking for `org.other.SomeClass`, it would appear in the jar as `/org/other/SomeClass.class`.

Comment: I was hoping to _not_ having to resort to that. For one, it's slow, but we may also get multiple results and _still_ wouldn't know which caused the problem, having to check  each instance. (The offending class is from Jackson which is widely used.) I take that, to your knowledge, there's no option for `java` or other tools-based way to solve the issue?

Comment: @Raphael, It can't be *too* slow.  Java does it for every single class it loads.  But if you mean it would be slow to do manually then yes, probably so.  Thus, I would write a simple script to help.  But I think you are missing the key point here: although the class may appear in multiple jars, you do know which appearance is the problem.  *Supposing you check the jars in classpath order*, it is the first you find.

Comment: This certainly seems to be a workable approach that can be scripted, provided one can easily and accurately determine the class path order (very doable via `jinfo <id>`). So, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'd do something like the following:

```
log.info(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/acme/MyClass.class"));
```

For the class `com.acme.MyClass`.

Comment: Trying this with `java/util/ArrayList`, I get `null`.

Comment: Indeed, this method doesn't work with runtime (rt.jar) classes. Is it the class `ArrayList` causing the problem?

Comment: No, I was trying to quickly check whether your method was effective.

Comment: @Raphael, why don't you try it on your use case then? It is for your use case that I provided this answer. It is very unlikely that your error is due to a JRE class (Java maintained backward compatibility until Java 8).

Comment: On it. (Waiting for a colleague to try it.) Of course it some library class and not a standard lib class...

Comment: Ad snark: Well, you will have to admit that your answer is _little_ thin in the ways of disclaimers and explanations. I had no reason to expect it to work after it failed for what I thought would be a trivial case. In my experience, one-line answers are rarely useful, well-intended or not, so 1min was all I was going to spend.

Comment: Too bad, because it's working perfectly here:
https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/wlf
you can check it yourself.